First use of gls doesn't work as expected - no description through \glsentrydesc
I am trying to get the description of a gls entry at the first occurance followed by the abbreviation in parenthesis. See the minimum working example (MWE).
MWE:
\listfiles
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makenoidxglossaries
\newglossaryentry{lol}
{
    name={LOL},
    description={laughing out loud},
    first={\glsentrydesc{lol} (\glsentrytext{lol})}
}
%first={\glsentrydesc{lol} (\glsentrytext{lol})}

\begin{document}

Another abbreviation is \gls{lol}.
\newline{}

\glsentrydesc{lol}.

\printnoidxglossary[title=Symbols and Abbreviations]

\end{document}

Yielded output:

Instead of the description there seems to be just a blank space.

Operating system (OS): Windows 11
TeX Live

Document compiled with two methods, both yield the same result:

via several runs of the following PowerShell command: pdflatex MWE.tex
Using TeXStudio 4.8.4 with standard settings

Any help would be highly appreciated!
Output of the log file:
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2024.10.11)  4 DEC 2024 03:18
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**MWE.tex
(./MWE.tex
LaTeX2e <2024-06-01> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2024-09-10>
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrartcl.cls
Document Class: scrartcl 2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script document class (article)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
Package: scrkbase 2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent b
asics and keyval usage)

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
Package: scrbase 2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent 
basics and keyval usage)

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty
Package: scrlfile 2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script package (file load hooks)

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile-hook.sty
Package: scrlfile-hook 2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script package (using LaTeX hooks)


(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlogo.sty
Package: scrlogo 2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script package (logo)
)))
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks17
)
Applying: [2021/05/01] Usage of raw or classic option list on input line 252.
Already applied: [0000/00/00] Usage of raw or classic option list on input line
 368.
))
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty
Package: tocbasic 2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
\scr@dte@tocline@numberwidth=\skip49
\scr@dte@tocline@numbox=\box52
)
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `toc'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `toc' on input line 133.
Class scrartcl Info: File `scrsize11pt.clo' used instead of
(scrartcl)           file `scrsize11.clo' to setup font sizes on input line 244
1.

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize11pt.clo
File: scrsize11pt.clo 2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt
)
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty
Package: typearea 2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script package (type area)
\ta@bcor=\skip50
\ta@div=\count194
\ta@hblk=\skip51
\ta@vblk=\skip52
\ta@temp=\skip53
\footheight=\skip54
Package typearea Info: These are the values describing the layout:
(typearea)             DIV  = 10
(typearea)             BCOR = 0.0pt
(typearea)             \paperwidth      = 597.50793pt
(typearea)              \textwidth      = 418.25555pt
(typearea)              DIV departure   = -6%
(typearea)              \evensidemargin = 17.3562pt
(typearea)              \oddsidemargin  = 17.3562pt
(typearea)             \paperheight     = 845.04694pt
(typearea)              \textheight     = 595.80026pt
(typearea)              \topmargin      = -25.16531pt
(typearea)              \headheight     = 17.0pt
(typearea)              \headsep        = 20.40001pt
(typearea)              \topskip        = 11.0pt
(typearea)              \footskip       = 47.6pt
(typearea)              \baselineskip   = 13.6pt
(typearea)              on input line 1799.
)
\c@part=\count195
\c@section=\count196
\c@subsection=\count197
\c@subsubsection=\count198
\c@paragraph=\count199
\c@subparagraph=\count266
\scr@dte@section@maxnumwidth=\skip55
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrartcl)           for `\section on input line 5082.
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrartcl)           for `\section on input line 5082.
\scr@dte@part@maxnumwidth=\skip56
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=false'
(scrartcl)           for `\part on input line 5090.
\scr@dte@subsection@maxnumwidth=\skip57
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrartcl)           for `\subsection on input line 5100.
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrartcl)           for `\subsection on input line 5100.
\scr@dte@subsubsection@maxnumwidth=\skip58
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrartcl)           for `\subsubsection on input line 5110.
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrartcl)           for `\subsubsection on input line 5110.
\scr@dte@paragraph@maxnumwidth=\skip59
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrartcl)           for `\paragraph on input line 5121.
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrartcl)           for `\paragraph on input line 5121.
\scr@dte@subparagraph@maxnumwidth=\skip60
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrartcl)           for `\subparagraph on input line 5131.
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrartcl)           for `\subparagraph on input line 5131.
\abovecaptionskip=\skip61
\belowcaptionskip=\skip62
\c@pti@nb@sid@b@x=\box53
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `lof'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `lof' on input line 6309.
\scr@dte@figure@maxnumwidth=\skip63
\c@figure=\count267
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `lot'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `lot' on input line 6325.
\scr@dte@table@maxnumwidth=\skip64
\c@table=\count268
Class scrartcl Info: Redefining `\numberline' on input line 6495.
\bibindent=\dimen141
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/base/glossaries.sty
Package: glossaries 2024/11/01 v4.55 (NLCT)

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2024/03/16 v1.1e Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2022/06/16 v2.9 package option processing (HA)

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks18
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks19
)
\XKV@depth=\count269
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mfirstuc/mfirstuc.sty
Package: mfirstuc 2022/10/14 v2.08 (NLCT)

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count270
)
\@glsmfirst=\toks20
\@glsmrest=\toks21
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xfor/xfor.sty
Package: xfor 2009/02/05 v1.05 (NLCT)
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks22
\ex@=\dimen142
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/datatool/datatool-base.sty
Package: datatool-base 2019/09/27 v2.32 (NLCT)

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2024/05/23 v2.17q AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip65

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2021/08/26 v2.01 AMS text
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen143
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2022/04/08 v2.04 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count271
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 233.
\uproot@=\count272
\leftroot@=\count273
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 398.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \colon on input line 409.
\classnum@=\count274
\DOTSCASE@=\count275
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 495.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 498.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 619.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box54
\strutbox@=\box55
LaTeX Info: Redefining \big on input line 721.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Big on input line 722.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bigg on input line 723.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Bigg on input line 724.
\big@size=\dimen144
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 742.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 743.
\macc@depth=\count276
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bmod on input line 904.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pmod on input line 909.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \smash on input line 939.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \relbar on input line 969.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Relbar on input line 970.
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count277
\dotsspace@=\muskip17
\c@parentequation=\count278
\dspbrk@lvl=\count279
\tag@help=\toks23
\row@=\count280
\column@=\count281
\maxfields@=\count282
\andhelp@=\toks24
\eqnshift@=\dimen145
\alignsep@=\dimen146
\tagshift@=\dimen147
\tagwidth@=\dimen148
\totwidth@=\dimen149
\lineht@=\dimen150
\@envbody=\toks25
\multlinegap=\skip66
\multlinetaggap=\skip67
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks26
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2953.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2954.
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/substr/substr.sty
Package: substr 2009/10/20 v1.2 Handle substrings
\c@su@anzahl=\count283
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/datatool/datatool-fp.sty
Package: datatool-fp 2019/09/27 v2.32 (NLCT)

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp.sty
Package: fp 1995/04/02

`Fixed Point Package', Version 0.8, April 2, 1995 (C) Michael Mehlich
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/defpattern.sty
Package: defpattern 1994/10/12
\actioncount=\count284
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-basic.sty
Package: fp-basic 1996/05/13
\FP@xs=\count285
\FP@xia=\count286
\FP@xib=\count287
\FP@xfa=\count288
\FP@xfb=\count289
\FP@rega=\count290
\FP@regb=\count291
\FP@regs=\count292
\FP@times=\count293
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-addons.sty
Package: fp-addons 1995/03/15
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-snap.sty
Package: fp-snap 1995/04/05
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-exp.sty
Package: fp-exp 1995/04/03
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-trigo.sty
Package: fp-trigo 1995/04/14
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-pas.sty
Package: fp-pas 1994/08/29
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-random.sty
Package: fp-random 1995/02/23
\FPseed=\count294
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-eqn.sty
Package: fp-eqn 1995/04/03
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-upn.sty
Package: fp-upn 1996/10/21
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-eval.sty
Package: fp-eval 1995/04/03
)))
\@dtl@toks=\toks27
\@dtl@tmpcount=\count295
\dtl@tmplength=\skip68
\dtl@sortresult=\count296
\@dtl@numgrpsepcount=\count297
\@dtl@datatype=\count298
\dtl@codeA=\count299
\dtl@codeB=\count300
\@dtl@foreach@level=\count301
)
\gls@level=\count302
\@gls@tmpb=\toks28
\gls@tmplen=\skip69
\glskeylisttok=\toks29
\glslabeltok=\toks30
\glsshorttok=\toks31
\glslongtok=\toks32

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-hypernav.sty
Package: glossary-hypernav 2024/11/01 v4.55 (NLCT)
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-list.sty
Package: glossary-list 2024/11/01 v4.55 (NLCT)
\glslistdottedwidth=\skip70
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-long.sty
Package: glossary-long 2024/11/01 v4.55 (NLCT)

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/longtable.sty
Package: longtable 2024-04-26 v4.20 Multi-page Table package (DPC)
\LTleft=\skip71
\LTright=\skip72
\LTpre=\skip73
\LTpost=\skip74
\LTchunksize=\count303
\LTcapwidth=\dimen151
\LT@head=\box56
\LT@firsthead=\box57
\LT@foot=\box58
\LT@lastfoot=\box59
\LT@gbox=\box60
\LT@cols=\count304
\LT@rows=\count305
\c@LT@tables=\count306
\c@LT@chunks=\count307
\LT@p@ftn=\toks33
)
Class scrartcl Info: longtable captions redefined on input line 47.
\glsdescwidth=\skip75
\glspagelistwidth=\skip76
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-super.sty
Package: glossary-super 2024/11/01 v4.55 (NLCT)

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/supertabular/supertabular.sty
Package: supertabular 2024/07/20 v4.2c the supertabular environment
\c@tracingst=\count308
\ST@wd=\dimen152
\ST@rightskip=\skip77
\ST@leftskip=\skip78
\ST@parfillskip=\skip79
\ST@pageleft=\dimen153
\ST@headht=\dimen154
\ST@tailht=\dimen155
\ST@pagesofar=\dimen156
\ST@pboxht=\dimen157
\ST@rowht=\dimen158
\ST@prevht=\dimen159
\ST@toadd=\dimen160
\ST@dimen=\dimen161
\ST@pbox=\box61
))
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-tree.sty
Package: glossary-tree 2024/11/01 v4.55 (NLCT)
\glstreeindent=\skip80
))
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2024-05-08 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count309
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box62
)
(./MWE.aux)
\openout1 = `MWE.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 14.
Package scrbase Info: activating english \abstractname on input line 14.
Package scrbase Info: activating english \partname on input line 14.
Package scrbase Info: activating english \figurename on input line 14.
Package scrbase Info: activating english \tablename on input line 14.
Package scrbase Info: activating english \contentsname on input line 14.
Package scrbase Info: activating english \listfigurename on input line 14.
Package scrbase Info: activating english \listtablename on input line 14.
Package scrbase Info: activating english \refname on input line 14.
Package scrbase Info: activating english \indexname on input line 14.

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 16--18

 []

Using TeX to sort glossary entries---this may take a while


[1

{c:/texlive/2024/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./MWE.aux)
 ***********
LaTeX2e <2024-06-01> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2024-09-10>
 ***********


 *File List*
scrartcl.cls    2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script document class (article)
scrkbase.sty    2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent bas
ics and keyval usage)
 scrbase.sty    2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent b
asics and keyval usage)
scrlfile.sty    2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script package (file load hooks)
scrlfile-hook.sty    2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script package (using LaTeX hooks)
 scrlogo.sty    2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script package (logo)
  keyval.sty    2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
tocbasic.sty    2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
scrsize11pt.clo    2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt)
typearea.sty    2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script package (type area)
glossaries.sty    2024/11/01 v4.55 (NLCT)
  ifthen.sty    2024/03/16 v1.1e Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
 xkeyval.sty    2022/06/16 v2.9 package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
mfirstuc.sty    2022/10/14 v2.08 (NLCT)
etoolbox.sty    2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
    xfor.sty    2009/02/05 v1.05 (NLCT)
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
datatool-base.sty    2019/09/27 v2.32 (NLCT)
 amsmath.sty    2024/05/23 v2.17q AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2021/08/26 v2.01 AMS text
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    2022/04/08 v2.04 operator names
  substr.sty    2009/10/20 v1.2 Handle substrings
datatool-fp.sty    2019/09/27 v2.32 (NLCT)
      fp.sty    1995/04/02
defpattern.sty    1994/10/12
fp-basic.sty    1996/05/13
fp-addons.sty    1995/03/15
 fp-snap.sty    1995/04/05
  fp-exp.sty    1995/04/03
fp-trigo.sty    1995/04/14
  fp-pas.sty    1994/08/29
fp-random.sty    1995/02/23
  fp-eqn.sty    1995/04/03
  fp-upn.sty    1996/10/21
 fp-eval.sty    1995/04/03
glossary-hypernav.sty    2024/11/01 v4.55 (NLCT)
glossary-list.sty    2024/11/01 v4.55 (NLCT)
glossary-long.sty    2024/11/01 v4.55 (NLCT)
longtable.sty    2024-04-26 v4.20 Multi-page Table package (DPC)
glossary-super.sty    2024/11/01 v4.55 (NLCT)
supertabular.sty    2024/07/20 v4.2c the supertabular environment
glossary-tree.sty    2024/11/01 v4.55 (NLCT)
l3backend-pdftex.def    2024-05-08 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
 ***********

 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 8432 strings out of 473579
 159725 string characters out of 5732262
 728825 words of memory out of 5000000
 31265 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 559262 words of font info for 40 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 108i,7n,107p,10898b,272s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
<c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb><c:/texl
ive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmssbx10.pfb>
Output written on MWE.pdf (1 page, 25742 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 18 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 10 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)




If I remember correctly, also here you have to compile twice. Did you do that?

I found the solution, even though I don't really understand what was wrong with my first try - maybe somebody is able to explain it.
Simply replacing the \glsentrydesc command with the \glsdesc command inside the \newglossaryentry environment did the job. It follows the whole minimum working example:
\listfiles
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makenoidxglossaries
\newglossaryentry{lol}
{
    name={LOL},
    description={laughing out loud},
    first={\glsdesc{lol} (\glsentrytext{lol})},
}

\begin{document}

Another abbreviation is \gls{lol}.
In the main part of the document the command seems to work:
\glsentrydesc{lol}.
What about the second \gls{lol}?

\printnoidxglossary[title=Symbols and Abbreviations]

\end{document}

This produces the desired output, see the following screenshot.

